# safe-ethers-lib: can't resolve stream when creating new ethAdapter

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk

Getting this problem whenever I try to run

```
const ethAdapter = new EthersAdapter({
      ethers,
      signer: safeOwner
    })
```

using the safe-ethers-lib

[image]

Comment: That's a dependency that should be installed

Answer (score 0):

Install the missing dependencies. For me it was `stream`, `stream-browserify` and `assert`

```
yarn add stream stream-browserify assert
```